# JSON error message appears before survey is closed within SurveyMonkey window on Android

Tags: surveymonkey

We defined a survey and are using SurveyMonkey SDK to display the survey on Android.

When a user choses to close the survey without proceeding, a white background containing the (correct) error code appears:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3xZc.jpg

Right after this is shown, onActivityResult() is invoked and the survey closes.

We looked into API and double-checked survey configuration for any debug options that might be enabled (or similar).

The following test case triggers the problem:
1. user opens a survey
2. user does not complete survey, but closes it instead by clicking the "X" button

Expected: Survey closes, SDK returns correctly:

```
{"error": {"reason": "user_exited_survey", "code": 200}}
```

Actual result: Survey is hidden, the error code that is expected is shown in the top-left corner of the WebView; after a few moments, the activity is closed and SDK returns correctly:

```
{"error": {"reason": "user_exited_survey", "code": 200}}
```

The user is able to see the JSON response for a few moments before the survey activity is closed, which is affecting user experience.

Is there any way to disable this text?